# Migration to the latest drools

Tags: drools, java-11

Anyone please share the migration guide or tools if available.
Need to migrate to the latest drools as the current version in use 4.0.7 is not working in Java 11 when upgraded from Java 8.

The classes currently in use seem to be not available in latest version 7.61.0:

```
import org.drools.RuleBase;
import org.drools.RuleBaseConfiguration;
import org.drools.RuleBaseFactory;
import org.drools.RuleBaseConfiguration.AssertBehaviour;
import org.drools.facttemplates.FactTemplate;
import org.drools.rule.Package;

RuleBaseConfiguration confRuleBase = new RuleBaseConfiguration();
// Be sure we use equality, not identity for facts.
confRuleBase.setAssertBehaviour(AssertBehaviour.EQUALITY);
confRuleBase.setShadowProxy( false );
// Create a rule base
RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase(confRuleBase);
```

How to convert this code to Drools 7.61.0?

Answer (score 3):

Drools 4 and Drools 7 are very different, there are no migration guides from those two specific version.

You might consider migrating each minor version, but I suggest instead to take the rules written and start from a new Drools 7 project and import your rules and the test suite

Comment: Absolutely this. I had to do a Drools 5 -> 7 migration and it was painful. I ended up touching almost every single rule and rewrote a large chunk of our "fire rules" framework and logic. It was effectively a rewrite at the end of the day.

Comment: drools-core jar file doesn't have the classes in old drools. What is the jar and class in latest drools for the old RuleBase class? We have drl files which will be compiled and saved in the DB during deployment process. Those rules will be triggered when MDB processed the messages from the queue during runtime.

Comment: Is the release notes available for drools versions above 5?

Comment: They're in the documentation itself. Note that a lot of the same general concepts exist but got moved/renamed. But some stuff just isn't necessary anymore (eg. the assert behavior is 'equality' by default.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas any chance you documented the steps you had to take for migrating from drools 5 to 7? I am having a hard time with it.